# Android: AutoCompleteTextView top margin on ListView

Tags: android, android-listview, autocompletetextview

The AutoCompleteTextView displays a ListView in a popup for auto completion. Attached is the image detailing the problem. Just before the first item, there is little white margin. This margin is only visible on the top of the list. This problem is seen on device running 2.3, while on 4.x this problem is not visible.

[image]

Can somebody point out the reason for this behavior and a way to fix it.

The code for Layout containing AutoCompleteTextview

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:paddingLeft="8dp"
          android:paddingRight="8dp"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_width="match_parent">

<AutoCompleteTextView
        android:id="@+id/menu_search_field"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/textfield_searchview_holo_light"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:hint="@string/search_hint"
        android:imeOptions="actionSearch"
        android:lines="1"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textColor="@color/header_text_color"
        android:textColorHint="@color/header_hint_text_color"
        android:textSize="14dip"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

The layout defining the item in the Listview.

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:background="@android:color/black"
    android:ellipsize="end"
    >
</TextView>
```

And the drawable for textfield_searchview_holo_light

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_focused="true"  android:drawable="@drawable/textfield_search_default_holo_dark" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/textfield_search_default_holo_dark" />
</selector>
```

Thanks.

Comment: Can you post the layout file of this view?

Comment: might be a problem with the style used by the drop down(since you pointed out that the problem is device specific). However you need to post the layout code for the view.

Comment: Hey Everyone... Does anyone know any solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to add XML attribute to your AutoCompleteTextView:

```
android:popupBackground="color_what_you_want_to_background"
```

in your case something like

```
android:popupBackground="@android:color/black"
```

Hope, it helps you

Comment: Thanks a lot. But isnt this a work around? Why is the margin present in the first place. Is it a bug? Your solution fixed my problem though.

Comment: @SwapsAgNO3 Do not know if bug is it.. This behavior is strange for first item.. But happy, that it solved your problem